# serialize no retorna los datos de un form

Tags: javascript, serialización

Cuando mando a llamar la funcion serialize(); al parecer los datos no son capturados de form, he visto en otros sitios y no encuentro error en el codigo. Pero cuando paro la ejecucion en excepciones se detiene en el console.log

```
var guardar= function(){
    $('form').on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var frm=$('input').serialize();
        console.log(frm);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haces mal en ejecutar el método serialize() en un input, te recomiendo ejecutarlo sobre el formulario, y para estar seguros de obtener los datos en caso de que tengas múltiples formularios en una misma página te recomiendo usar `$(this).serialize()` encaja con tu código ya que esta línea va dentro de la función del evento.

Answer (score 1):

**.serialize()** se ejecuta desde el formulario y no desde los input, deberias cambiar

```
$("input").serialize()

por

$("form").serialize()
```

abajo un ejemplo

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  console.log($("form").serialize())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action=""> 
    Nombre: 
    <input type="text" name="Nombre" value="nombre ejemplo"> 
    <br> Apellidos: 
    <input type="text" name="Apellidos" value="apellidos ejemplo"> 
    <br> 
</form>

<button>Mostrar serialize</button>
```